# indexof a string from a list in another list

Tags: c#, list, indexof

i have the following code:

```
    foreach (var str in usedCSS)
    {
        if (CSS.Contains(str))
            Response.Write(str);
        else
            Response.Write("Could not find: " + x + "<br />");
    }
```

which dosent do exactly what i need, and i cant figure out what to do.

- `usedCSS` is a `List<string>`
- `CSS` is also a `List<string>`

the diffrence between them is that `usedCSS` contains only the css style name e.g: `.CssStyle`
and `CSS` Contains the full style e.g: `.CssStyle {font-weight:bold)`

what i want is to print out all the actual CSS code that is in `usedCSS`.
i know i should use `IndexOf`, but cant figure out how to.

I ask for your kind help.

Comment: Your requirements are a little unclear. Could you give an example of expected input and output? (i.e. values of usedCSS, CSS, and str, and what you'd want to have output to the console)

Comment: somehow, im sure i gave examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
foreach (var str in usedCSS)
{
    if (CSS.Any( x=> x.StartsWith(str))
        Response.Write(str);
    else
        Response.Write("Could not find: " + x + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: what about the oposite way ? is there a way to do it ?
by oposite, i mean iterate the CSS list, and match on the usedCSS.

Comment: since you dont seem to answer, should i open another question? :\

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var str in usedCSS)
{
    if (CSS.Any(c => c.Contains(str)))
        Response.Write(str);
    else
        Response.Write("Could not find: " + x + "<br />");
}
```

alternatively, you could also use `c.StartsWith(str)` i think.

Comment: .Contains alone could not match them.
since it will try to exact match the strings.

Comment: @Dementic: That's not true in this case - Bala's solution also should work since the `Contains` that is used is `string.Contains()` which will return true if there is a match anywhere in the string

Comment: after testing it, you are right. but i was allways thinking that `.Contains` will match the excat string. Guess i was wrong.